# Is it possible to solve this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A function $f$ satisfies: $f'(x)=1-e^{-2a(1-f(x))}$ for a constant $a$ and $f(0)=0$.

I guess $f$ might be some logarithmic function. Is there a systematic way to solve this kind of ODE?

Comment: The DE is separable ...

Comment: Are you familiar with separation of variables?

Comment: I am trying it now. Something like $g(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$ and then $\int g(y) dy=\int f(x)dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach of course overcomplicated.

---

Rewriting the problem with the familiar notation in ODE as follows:
$$(\text{E}):\begin{cases}y'(x)=1-e^{-2a(1-y(x))},\\ y(0)=0, \quad  a\in \mathbb{R}. \end{cases}$$
The ODE we can solve as **exact equation**:
\begin{align*}
y'=1-e^{-2a(1-y)} &\implies \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=1-e^{-2a(1-y)},\\
&\implies \underbrace{\left(-1+e^{-2a(1-y)} \right)}_{=P(x,y)} {\rm d}x +\underbrace{(1)}_{=Q(x,y)}{\rm d}y=0,\quad \text{(F)}\\
&\implies \frac{\partial P}{\partial y }(x,y)\not=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x,y),\\
&\implies \text{(E) is nos exact equation}
\end{align*}
Find a integrating factor $\mu(y)$ such that
$$(\text{G}):\quad  \mu(y)P(x,y){\rm d}x+\mu(y)Q(x,y){\rm d}y=0 \implies \text{(G) is exact equation}. $$
This mean $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu(y)P(x,y))=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\mu(y)Q(x,y)), \quad (*)$$
Solving for $\mu(y)$, we get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu(y)P(x,y))=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\mu(y)Q(x,y)) \implies \boxed{\mu(y)=-\frac{e^{2a(1-y)}}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}}, \quad a\in \mathbb{R}.$$
Multiply both sides of $\text{(F)}$ by $\mu(y)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{(H)}: \quad \underbrace{\left[-\frac{e^{2a(1-y)}}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1} \right]\left[-1+e^{-2a(1-y)} \right]}_{=R(x,y)} {\rm d}x+\underbrace{\left[-\frac{e^{2a(1-y)}}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1} \right]\left[1\right]}_{=S(x,y)} {\rm d}y=0
\end{align*}
Hence $\text{(H)}$ satisfy the condition $(*)$ then is a exact equation.

Now, there exists a function $f$ such that $$\text{(I)}: \begin{cases} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=R(x,y),\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=S(x,y) \end{cases}$$
where $$R(x,y)=1 \quad \text{and} \quad S(x,y)=\frac{e^{2a(1-y)}}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}$$
and the general solution for the ODE is given by $$f(x,y)=C, \quad C\in \mathbb{R}$$

Solving for $f(x,y)$ in $\text{(I)}$ we have
$$f(x,y)=-\int \frac{e^{2a(1-y)}}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1} {\rm d}y-\frac{x}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}+\frac{e^{2a(1-y)}x}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}$$
Then the general solution is given by
$$-\int \frac{e^{2a(1-y)}}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1} {\rm d}y-\frac{x}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}+\frac{e^{2a(1-y)}x}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}=C, \quad C\in \mathbb{R}$$
Then the particular solution is given by the expression
$$\begin{cases}\displaystyle -\int \frac{e^{2a(1-y)}}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1} {\rm d}y-\frac{x}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}+\frac{e^{2a(1-y)}x}{e^{2a(1-y)}-1}=C,\\
y(0)=0, a\in \mathbb{R} \end{cases}$$

---

Quick check of the solution obtained:

- With $a=1$ we have the general solution
  $$\frac{y}{e^{2}}-\frac{\log|e^{2}-e^{2y}|}{2e^{2}}-\frac{x}{-e^{2y}+e^{2}}+\frac{e^{-2(1-y)}x}{-e^{2y}+e^{2}}=C$$
  Soving for $y(x)$ and subsitute $y(0)=0$ we have the particular solution
  $$y(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\log\left|(-1+e^{2})e^{-2x}+1 \right|+1$$
  and it is indeed a particular solution for $\text{(E)}$ when $a=1$.

Answer (score 6):

$$f'(x)=1-e^{-2a(1-f(x))}$$
The DE is sparable. Substitute $1-f = y$:
$$y'(x)=e^{-2ay}-1$$
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{e^{-2ay}-1}=\int dx$$
Then substitute
$$u=e^{-2ay}$$
$${du}=-2ae^{-2ay}dy$$
$${du}=-2audy$$
So that:
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{e^{-2ay}-1}=\int dx$$
$$-\dfrac 1 {2a}\int \dfrac {du}{u(u-1)}=\int dx$$
Use fraction decomposition method.